# Regex to allow only alphabet and special alphabets like é

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I want a regex which only allows a-z A-Z and special characters like é (accented). I don't want any special characters like @,.$%^&"

```
lastName.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    inputValidation.bind({
        // reg: /^[A-Za-z ]+$/,
        reg: /^[a-zA-Z]*$/,
        element: lastName,
        error: 'Only alphabets allowed!',
    })
);
```

I have tried many regex but they also restrict characters like é. I want to allow special alphabets and simple alphabets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
lastName.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    inputValidation.bind({
        reg: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]*$/,
        element: lastName,
        error: 'Only alphabets allowed!',
    })
);
```